# unset a filetype option when switching to any other filetype?

Tags: vim

I have this line in my .vimrc:

`au filetype python set colorcolumn=80`

I would prefer if the colorcolumn disappeared when I switched to a non-python buffer. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setlocal to set that to just the buffer you want.

```
au filetype python setlocal colorcolumn=80
```

You can also abbreviate it to setl

```
au filetype python setl colorcolumn=80
```

Comment: Or just put `setlocal colorcolumn=80` in a `python` ftplugin.

Comment: Thank you. Why did I wait so many years to ask this question?